# Drive API V2: Use Service Account to set useByDefault boolean for a specific app on a user's Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

Is it possible to programatically set the useByDefault Boolean for an App on a user's Google Drive?

According to: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/apps I can List all Apps, or Get a specific App... I would have expected to see a SET command.

I'm a Google Super Administrator, and we have Read&Write for Google Chrome extension force installed for our students, but they still need to manually navigate to their drive settings and change the useByDefault checkbox before the extension can work properly with PDF files.

I've already created a working Service account with the following scopes: DriveService.Scope.Drive, DriveService.Scope.DriveFile, DriveService.Scope.DriveMetadata, DriveService.Scope.DriveAppsReadonly
I'm currently using C#.

The information on the extension we are using is:

> "kind": "drive#app",    "id": "982754197589",    "name": "Read&Write
>   for Google Chrome™",    "shortDescription": "Experience PDFs in a
>   whole new way with Texthelp’s new PDF Reader.",    "longDescription":
>   "",    "supportsCreate": false,    "supportsImport": false,
>   "supportsMultiOpen": false,    "supportsOfflineCreate": false,
>   "installed": true,    "authorized": true,    "hasDriveWideScope":
>   true,    "useByDefault": false,    "productUrl":
>   "https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/detail/982754197589",
>   "productId": "ohfjebjepnlldifcbcfmopifaebcjehc",    "openUrlTemplate":
>   "https://pdf.texthelp.com/pdfreader?state=%7B%22ids%22:%5B%22{ids}%22%5D,%22exportIds%22:%5B%22{exportIds}%22%5D,%22action%22:%22open%22,%22userId%22:%22110948624529639950901%22%7D",
>   "primaryMimeTypes": [
>       "application/epub+zip",
>       "application/pdf",
>       "application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk.982754197589"    ],    "primaryFileExtensions": [
>       "pdf",
>       "epub"    ],    "icons": [
>       {
>        "category": "application",
>        "size": 10,
>        "iconUrl": "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-eFdHkrx3NH8/VQ_ez9gL7sI/AAAAAAAABjo/qGf6VEFHbpM/s10-c-k/16.png"
>       }

I'd appreciate any insight on the matter.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only two methods for apps in google drive list and get.  There is no way of updating these settings programmatically and as far as i can see these methods aren't available at all in Google drive v3.

I think your going to have to do it manually